# Magento 2 : How the product setting "Notify for Quantity Below" will work?

Tags: magento2, email-templates, inventory

I want to set the email template  to Notify if the product quantity below particular quantity and I found this setting in product.

> Notify for Quantity Below

But not sure how this will work and where we can define the email template for this. Is it for the same ?

Comment: http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/inventory-product-stock-options.html or refer http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-configure-and-manage-inventory-settings.html#gref You’ll be informed with RSS Feeds. In order to be informed, you need to subscribe.

Comment: The second document is for magento 1 but not for magento 2. And the first doc is not explanation for this point.

Comment: which magento2 version you are using?

Comment: I am using Magento 2.0.7